# Forward geocoding using Google Maps SDK on iOS 6

Tags: ios, google-maps, geocoding, clgeocoder

Is there any method that implement forward geocoding on Google Maps SDK? I don't want to use the Google Maps API Web Services.
Thank you

Comment: Would you consider using the native `CLGeocoder` class?

Comment: Yes could be fine for me. Thank you

Comment: CLGeocoder seems to be inaccurate out of USA. I've tried for UK. Though UK is mentioned in full supported countries list [(check here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2289/_index.html) but still it provide data no where near accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, you can use the native [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Forward-geocoding requests take a user-readable address and find the corresponding latitude and longitude value.

```
CLGeocoder geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"1 Infinite Loop"
     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
         {
             // Process the placemark.
         }
}];
```

Comment: `CLGeocoder` has small requests limit per day (about 50 or so). It is better to use `Google API` with authored key (limit is about 1500 per day).